# Python - percentage symbol on imports

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm following this [tutorial](https://medium.com/thealexfreeman/animation-with-matplotlib-python-70c952c55d8) and I've tried to copy the code of the first example.
this is the first lines on the example:

```py
from PIL import Image
import random
import time
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import imshow, show
import matplotlib.animation as animation

#this is crucial to animation in matplotlib
%matplotlib notebook
.
.
.
```

As you can see, right underneath the imports, there is this line `%matplotlib notebook`. this line is causing a problems because it doesn't recognized as a command.
this is the problem description: `Statement expected, found Py:PERC` and `End of statement expected`

My question is - what is the meaning of the percentage symbol in this case and why doesn't it work?

Comment: The percent symbol here is a Jupyter notebook convention https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#built-in-magic-commands so you'll want to run that code from a notebook.

Comment: @chris It's also the syntax for an ipython magic function, right? It's strange that the tutorial doesn't mention either.

Comment: Like @Barmar says, it's not Python code, but an [IPython magic](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html), which works in Jupyter because Jupyter uses an IPython kernel. If you're writing a script and executing with Python itself, you can probably just leave it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This syntax is a Jupyter notebook convention. If you are not using Jupyter notebook, then you can probably remove this line.